# Streamsets Data Collector: Replace a Field With Its Child Value

Tags: etl, streamsets, data-pipeline

I have a data structure like this

```
{
  "id": 926267,
  "updated_sequence": 2304899,
  "published_at": {
      "unix": 1589574240,
      "text": "2020-05-15 21:24:00 +0100",
      "iso_8601": "2020-05-15T20:24:00Z"
  },
  "updated_at": {
      "unix": 1589574438,
      "text": "2020-05-15 21:27:18 +0100",
      "iso_8601": "2020-05-15T20:27:18Z"
  },

 }
```

I want to replace the `updated_at` field with its `unix` field value using Streamsets Data Collector. As far as I know, it can be done using field replacer. But I'm still didn't get it how to make a mapping expression. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Field Replacer, set **Fields** to `/rec/updated_at` and **New value** to `${record:value('/rec/updated_at/unix')}` and it will replace the value. See below.

[image]

[image]

Cheers,
Dash